# how to vectorize this sum of quotient in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 1 x n vectors a, b and c and want to calculate the sum of (a_i^2 + a_i*b_i)/c_i with i=1..n. Is there a way to vectorize this sum of quotient other than the obvious for loop? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for vectorisation. Use element wise operator as described in [Arithmetic Operators](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html).

```
sum((a.^2+a.*b)./c)
```

Comment: Thank you. The sum command gets me this error "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals". Do you know why?

Comment: i think you meant `sum((a.^2+a.*b)./c)`

Comment: @martin08: the only reason you would get that error is if you've previously used `sum` as a variable. `sum` is a MATLAB function, and if you used zellus' code without clearing the previous variable, you're likely to get this error. I would recommend naming variables different from inbuilt functions.